# Select First and last non empty/Blank column of a record MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below

```
|  Name  |    Date       |  Time1   |  Time2     | Time3  |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  Enoch  |  20/06/2018  |  8:00am  |  12:00pm  | 4:30pm |
| Fred    |  20/06/2018  |  7:00am  |  4:00pm   |        |
```

I want a query that can produce the below

```
| Name   |     Date   | First Time | Last Time |
| Enoch  | 20/06/2018 |   8:00am   | 4:30pm    |
| Fred   | 20/06/2018 |   7:00am   | 4:00pm    |
```

I can't think of anything. Please help... Thanks

Is a clocking system which a user can clock a maximum of 10 times; Time1 to Time10. If we are generating report. We want to select the first time a user clocked and the last time he clocked for the day to compute his time. Some users may clock 6 time a day, other may clock 2 or 3 times a day. Looking for a query that select the first Time the user clocked against the last time he clocked for the day. Been beating my mind up for days now

Comment: Is it always true that `Time1` is always filled first, `Time2`always second, etc? Or, could you have a row with `Time1` = 1PM and `Time2 = 9:30AM? Also, can you have more than one row for a given `Name` and `Date`, giving you multiple possible values for each column to consider?

Comment: Thank you. I will rewrite my question so it will be clear to understand.

Answer (score 2):

`COALESCE()` function returns the first non-null value between 2 (or  more) values:

```
SELECT Name, Date,
       COALESCE(Time1, Time2, Time3) AS First_Time,
       COALESCE(Time3, Time2, Time1) AS Last_Time
FROM tbl ;
```

Comment: COALESCE(Time3, Time2, Time1) AS Last_Time>> when Time3 is null it doesn't select Time2

Comment: @user9581732 that is not possible. Are you sure the value is null?

Comment: I think the value is empty.

Comment: SELECT Namee, Datee,
       COALESCE(NULLIF(Time1,''), NULLIF(Time2,''), NULLIF(Time3,'')) AS First_Time,
       COALESCE(NULLIF(Time3,''), NULLIF(Time2,''), NULLIF(Time1,'')) AS Last_Time
FROM timekart ;